# Linking To Related Articles In Django

Tags: django

I have a Django blog, and each article is associated with a certain category. On the detail page of each article, there is a card on the right side. This card has a header of "Related Articles" and has a list of the five most recent articles under that same category as the article currently being viewed. Below this list of related articles is a button that should link the user to all articles under that same category. But I can't seem to make the link to serve its desired purpose. On my index page, I can click on any category and get directed to a list of similar articles, but I can't achieve the same functionality from my detail page. How do I fix this?

Below are the relevant codes.

In my models.py,

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # generate a slug based on the post title
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts', 
    default='uncategorized')
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="post_likes")

    def get_api_like_url(self):
        return reverse('article:like-api', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # generate a slug based on the post title
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    # limits the number of characters shown on the html template when rendered
    def snippet(self):
        return self.post[:300] + '...'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

in my views.py,

```
def detail(request, slug):
    # the slug from the models.py is = to the slug passed in via the url request
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    # to filter based on category
    category = post.category
    # the category in the models is = to the category value above, and we exclude the current article
    related_articles = Post.objects.filter(category=category).exclude(id=post.id).order_by('-date')[:5]
    if related_articles.count() < 5:
        show_all = False
    else:
        show_all = True
    context = {'post': post,
               'related_articles': related_articles,
               'show_all': show_all
               }
    print(category.slug)
    return render(request, 'article/read.html', context)

def category_view(request, categories):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, name__exact=categories)
    posts = category.posts.all()

    category_slugs = categories.split(',')
    categories = Category.objects.filter(slug__in=category_slugs)
    articles = Post.objects.filter(category__in=categories)
    context = {'category': category,
               'posts': posts,
               'category_names': [category.name for category in categories],
               'articles': articles,
               }
    return render(request, 'article/category.html', context)
```

in my urls.py,

```
app_name = 'article'

urlpatterns = [
  path('category/<str:categories>/', views.category_view, name='category'),
]
```

in my index.html, the following works as intended

```
<span id="category"><a href="{% url 'article:category' post.category %}">{{post.category}}</a></span>
```

but I can't achieve similar functionality in my detail page. The detail.html has

```
<!-- Related Articles Card -->
        {% if related_articles %}
        <div id="related-articles">
            <div id="card">
                <h2>Articles in the same category</h2>
                <ul>
                  {% for related_article in related_articles %}
                    <li><a href="{{ related_article.get_absolute_url }}">{{ related_article.title }}</a></li>
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                <a href="{% url 'article:category' categories=related_articles.slug %}">View all related articles</a>
              </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a href="{% url 'article:category' categories=related_articles.slug %}">View all related articles</a>
```

This code does not work because `related_articles` is a Queryset, not an object. Hence you can change it to:

```
<a href="{% url 'article:category' categories=post.category %}">View all related articles</a>
```

This will work because you are sending the `post` is an object (of `Post` model) and you are sending it to the template via context variable.